# play video using url ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am struggling to play a video which is a url of the video file on a server. I have a view in which I display url from the web service. When I click the url(contained in a table cell) I want that a new view should appear with movie player on it playing the video. I have tried `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and also `MPMoviePlayerController` and various combinations of the two but I could not play the video  on simulator. Currently I don't have a device so please consider simulator as well as device while answering. Currently i am using:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
self.player= [[ MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
//self.player.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
[self.player.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
//self.player.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
self.player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
self.player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
self.player.moviePlayer.fullscreen = NO;
[self presentModalViewController:self.player animated:NO];
[self.player.moviePlayer play];
```

`filepath` is a `nsstring` containing the video url.

Answer (score 5):

Replace your this line : `NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];`

with this: `NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:filePath];` & then try.

My Code I am using `MPMOVIEPLAYERVIEWCONTROLLER`:

```
    NSData *geturl = [[videoparsing objectAtIndex:btntag]objectForKey:@"iurl"];
    myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:geturl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"myString..%@",myString);
    NSURL *fileURL=[NSURL URLWithString:myString];
    NSLog(@"fileURL..%@",fileURL);
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];
    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: I am update my answer you see what I am do & then make changes acc. to ur need...

Answer (score 1):

If `video file` is on `server` then

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
```

other should be change `movieSourceType` to `MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming` :

```
self.player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

Also

```
self.player.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
```

**EDIT** : Add :

```
  self.player.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
```

remove :

```
 [self.player.moviePlayer play];
```